# Bluetooth issue - no icon on the top bar

Tags: bluetooth

Just installed elementary OS for the first time and I do not see any option for Bluetooth.

Tried some commands but no success:

```
# rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no
```

I can not even see Bluetooth under `rfkill` and no Bluetooth icon.

I'm a beginner with Linux. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you are able to post the result of `lshw`? This guide may help you: https://chrisjean.com/how-to-find-hardware-devices-in-ubuntu-with-lshw/

Answer (score 0):

What Wi-Fi/Bluetooth chipset do you have? From there you can check if the right drivers are installed and loaded using `lsmod`. Also can you open an application called Bluetooth - it comes with the default installation.